# Hero Banner - Responsive Design

Tags: website-design, responsive-design

Is there a "best-pattern" for responsive banners?

I see this one all over the place:
[image]

...in fact, I haven't seen much else on responsive websites.

Essentially, the common theme seems to be a faded image behind centered text.

Is there a reason other text positions, imagery, and other elements aren't commonly used on responsive pages? This design seems a bit dry.

Some examples: 
nest.com
sofi.com
apple.com

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "best pattern" are you referring to the layout of the banner?

Comment: is there something you have better in mind?

Comment: Yes, the layout

Comment: This is what people do... Something looks good or what ever and they want to use it too. This style just became popular and that's pretty much why you see it everywhere. Go ahead... I'm not going to call the police if you want to design something original.

Comment: I think this answers this as well as anything else: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24757/how-do-design-trends-originate There is no "best". What's popular in 2015 may be completely different than what people copy in 2017.

Comment: No, there is no 'best' pattern. Use what works for your particular need.

Answer (score 1):

Responsive "design" by its very nature needs to be extremely minimalist so things can easily realign and relocate.

It's also fair to say that those that could do the best responsive design are not (yet) at all interested in it. The tools simply aren't ready.

So it's being done by those without a lot of creativity and problem solving ability in design, more code oriented folks playing with layout. Therefore it  is (at this stage) both incredibly simple and simplistic.

In all fairness to those that are attempting to do responsive "design", there's not a lot of tools available for doing any form of serious responsive layout and experimentation unless you know how to code. And coding and instinctive design capabilities are nearly mutually exclusive properties.

**CLARIFICATION**:
*Those sufficiently competent with code to be significantly experimental and exploratory through the medium aren't generally inclined to visual design, nor instinctively capable of good design.  And vice-versa.*

Perhaps the best current tool is Storyboards in the new Xcode 7, but it's got a learning curve far beyond the interests and passions of most designers, and isn't designed for web work. It's designed for making responsive apps for varying screen sizes and sections in the iOS and OS X worlds, but for experimenting with layout ideas it's probably the best tool of the moment, barring actually learning to code.

It's almost better to pick aspect ratios and sizes you'd like to design for, and go from there, manually. Greater initial pain for a much easier completion run.

Comment: "And coding and instinctive design capabilities are nearly mutually exclusive properties" = that's not true at all. The best developers I've met understand visual design and vice versa.

Comment: DA01, you can't say that's not true "at all" and then say "the best developers I've met". What about the worst developers you've met? Maybe @Confused got a point (well, he/she got my +1 at least!)

Comment: 'Responsive "design" by its very nature needs to be extremely minimalist' - no it doesn't.

Comment: Care to provide some proof?

Comment: Responsive design *tends* to be minimalist because a) it gained popularity while flat design is/was in fashion, b) it's much, much easier that way and c) it tends to be implemented by UX-oriented design teams which err towards minimalism (every flourish or decorative element needs to be able to prove its objective utility). In theory, you *could* have a design that was both perfectly responsive, and highly decorated/complex... but you'd be swimming against the tides of fashion, technology and the decision-making processes of most responsive design teams, for little benefit. +1

Comment: Why did flat design gain popularity, again? This is not the first time the aesthetic qualities currently known as "flat design" have been popular. What you're describing are symptoms of the trend, not the things that brought the trend into play.

Comment: @go-me mutually exclusive would imply there aren't visual designers who can code and vice versa. This is simply not true.

Comment: @confused the flat design trend primarily started with windows phone -- not responsive web design. One could argue the web, in general, has gone minimalist regardless of RWD.

Comment: "the flat design trend primarily started with windows phone" This is patently false. Flat design was a hugely popular, and the dominant trend and paradigm of web design long before Windows Phone began using it.

Comment: They key to the answer is not who, it's why and how it became popular. Think about the limitations of CSS and you'll be getting much closer to the origins of this resurgence in minimalism.

Comment: @DA01 We won't start playing with words. Design and coding are 2 different careers, and that's obviously what Confused meant. That's starting to be a topic that would fit well in a linguistic forum; what "at all" "always" "never" "nearly" mean!

Comment: @confused what limitations?

Comment: @go-me that's simply false. It *can* be separate careers, but often it's not. I am and have worked with many that can design the UI as well as build it.

Comment: @DA01 if you seriously think there are no limitations, or are unaware of the historical and existing limitations of CSS upon web design and development, then you're probably also naive about its use growth and significance in web design through the early and mid 00's. In which case there's no point attempting to explain the origins (how, why, when and where) of what we (currently) call "flat design".

Comment: I think the underlying problem with this answer is oversimplification. You're asserting various opinions as if they were fact without any evidence. There is no reason for a person to be less talented at coding because they're already talented at design. It's just not true.

Comment: And in addition to what Dom said, you're oversimplifying two very distinct things. A particular technology (CSS) and a particular visual design trend. Implying that the latter is due to the former is just an oversimplification of both topics.

Comment: And the coding and development are oversimplified by being compared to CSS. And the nuance of the english language are being oversimplified as well. I don't think "real" coders would appreciate having their skills compared to CSS customization. Personally, I have too much respect to call CSS "real coding". Everybody understood on the first sentence that it's possible to be good at both, but obviously it's 2 different fields; a mechanic can be a good painter, we got it, no one claims the opposite. All these comments are off-topic and full of ego! Yet no one posts a new answer.

Answer (score -1):

**If by "hero banner"** (5) you mean the header of a website, then it's mainly a matter of CSS and wanting to load the same image for all devices; *your example looks like using CSS and not a simple web banner*. There's a few reasons why a dev would use the same exact hero banner for all devices besides being faster to implement (1, 2) but each device can easily have its own hero banner and there aren't many design limits in this case. It's a matter of possibility, time/budget, and priorities.

---

**But if you mean a section with CSS and HTML for example**, the reason is time and budget, **dev often use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)**, and *in other occasions*, some of them prefer to not use jquery *to resize their galleries for example* (1, 2).

Already you can get a lot of different ways to create a responsive layout. AND ideally, the design shouldn't be overcharged with images. (2) It's normal the layout are minimalistic and doesn't have too many large images; it loads faster.

It simply takes more custom CSS code for each device if you decide to use another way to implement a responsive design but there is no "best" way, and anything can be done. And since solutions like Bootstrap exists, it's a nice shortcut to use that has already pre-defined ways to make the content "flow"; lotof dev will use it because it saves a lot of time, but a lot of websites end up having a similar style too. The important is that it fits well on each device, loads fast and if possible, looks nice too. It also has the benefit for dev of having only one website content to manage.(3)

The other way to not be limited by this is to create a website with a laptop, tablet and mobile version, with a distinct layout for each. Corporations will often use this if their priority is to present the design in the best way possible for each device (eg. promotions, contests.) On this level, it's a bit less of a puzzle to create a version for each device independently. But this could also be done by using different stylesheets. (3, 4)

You certainly see a lot of websites with a different responsive layout.

**These are some examples of different responsive layouts:**

http://stephencaver.com/

http://foodsense.is/

http://www.bk.com/

http://www.timhortons.com

http://hogash-demos.com/kallyas_joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&Itemid=156

---

Some references:

[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement#Introduction_and_background) The strategy is an evolution of a previous web design strategy known as "graceful degradation", wherein designers would create Web pages for the latest browsers that would also work well in older versions of browser software. Graceful degradation was supposed to allow the page to "degrade", or remain presentable even if certain technologies assumed by the design were not present, without being jarring to the user of such older software. Unfortunately, *upgrading is often not possible due to IT department policies, older hardware, and other reasons* (eg. government websites.) The "just upgrade" attitude also ignores deliberate user choices and the existence of a variety of browser platforms; many of which run on handhelds or in other contexts where *available bandwidth is restricted*, or *where support for sound or color and limited screen size*, for instance, are far different from the typical graphical desktop browser.

[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) "Although many publishers are starting to implement responsive designs, *one ongoing challenge for RWD is that some banner advertisements and videos are not fluid*. However, search advertising and (banner) display advertising support specific device platform targeting and different advertisement size formats for desktop, smartphone, and basic mobile devices."

[(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design#History) Jody Resnick, President of Trighton Interactive stated in his interview with Forbes, “Responsive websites simplify internet marketing and SEO. Instead of having to develop and manage content for multiple websites, businesses with responsive sites can take a unified approach to content management because they have only the one responsive site to manage.

[(4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design#History) "Different landing page URLs can be used for different platforms, or Ajax can be used to display different advertisement variants on a page. CSS tables permit hybrid fixed+fluid layouts".

[(5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image) Hero image is a term used in web design for a specific type of web banner. A hero image is a large banner image, prominently placed on a web page, generally in the front and center.

Edit: Added reference for hero banner in case the element has been misnamed in the question. Added some Wikipedia references that have already been approved by professional developers and quoting experts on the topic.

Comment: Bootstrap is certainly the most common responsive CSS grid framework (which, BTW, *usually* requires jQuery if you want to use the JS that comes with it) but this doesn't really address the specific question about  a banner design.

Comment: The question is mentioning hero banner but quite frankly, a banner is usually an image... I don't know for you, but the samples and description look like what someone would do with CSS... including me. Bootstrap can be used with or without jquery, I fail to see why you're mentioning this. I probably forgot a comma somewhere or I should have used bullet points for clarity, obviously.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, this pattern was made famous because of so many responsive themes available over the Internet. Also, many beginner designer, this one I have seen it personally, follow common patterns to design a website quickly, and this one is simple, easy and quick to create.